# When opening Dynebolic in Virtualbox, what Linux version do I select?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I am trying to install [Dynebolic](https://www.dyne.org/software/dynebolic/) in VirtualBox, but I do not know which linux version to install it as. I cannot find any help on the website either. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Other linux" with the appropriate architecture (in this case 32 bit) is a good bet. It does *not* particularly matter, other than that specific linux versions come with a sane set of settings for disk space and ram usage - which can be handy when running a popular distro or a derivative of it